# CSS click animation with opacity and particles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a custom click animation for my website, I want to do something like this:
[image: expected click animation]

Here's a capture from that gif
[image]
My first aproach was something like this:
[image]

It has some problems, for example when I click the animation is triggered but the animation follows the mouse instead of stay in the clicks coords, it lacks of many things like those shiny particles that spread across the click zone and that blurred halo, I dont know how to do this thing, someone know what should I do to accomplish this? like, what should I study or search to get what I want? I lack of expertise so I would really like some little guidance or anything

I dont know if this helps even a little bit but still I'll paste the code of my first approach

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: " + (e.pageY - 10) + "px; left: " + (e.pageX - 10) + "px;");
})

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  cursor.classList.add("expand");

  setTimeout(() => {
    cursor.classList.remove("expand");
  }, 500);
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.cursor {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes cursorAnim3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.expand {
  animation: cursorAnim3 .3s forwards;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

Any suggestion is welcome :c

Comment: Maybe you could adapt something like this to occur on a smaller, darker scale under your cursor? https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/avbPON

Comment: That will definitely help me, thank you! but how about the outer gradient-like border? the glowing-blurred halo? I did a little search and found how to use gradients in borders but the result is not quite what the halo looks like, have any idea?

Comment: Yup! Check this! https://jsfiddle.net/zf18bwen/1/ and also see this (what you want is a box shadow): https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I added to your code is an if statement inside of your `mousemove` event. I don't know how to explain, I just added it and it works... Hope that's what you wanted! :) PS: I also added `overflow-x: hidden` and `overflow-y: hidden` since the body size was increasing. It is located inside of

```
body {

}
```

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if (cursor.classList.length === 1) {
    cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: " + (e.pageY - 10) + "px; left: " + (e.pageX - 10) + "px;");
  }
})

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  cursor.classList.add("expand");

  setTimeout(() => {
    cursor.classList.remove("expand");
  }, 500);
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.cursor {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes cursorAnim3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.expand {
  animation: cursorAnim3 .3s forwards;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

Comment: @H3lltronik If this helped, please accept this as the correct answer. Thanks!